# Embedding ServerSockets in non-Server Applications

Tags: java, multithreading, networking, blocking

I have been attempting to develop an embedded webserver within an application that I have created.  Essentially we have our main process that creates a simple webserver (utilizing a ServerSocket) and then the main process (in theory) will go about it's business.

```
Main(){
    doingStuff();
    WebServer server = new WebServer();
    server.run();
    doingMoreStuff();
}

public class WebServer implements Runnable{
    ServerSocket inbound;

    //constructor
    WebServer(){
        inbound = new ServerSocket(9687);
    }

    public void Run(){
        Socket client;

        while(true){
            client = inbound.accept();
            SomeClass threadedClassThatHandlesClientMessage = new SomeClass(client);
            someclass.run();
        }
    }
}
```

In the preceding psuedo-code, I know that the thread with the ServerSocket accept() call blocks, ceasing the WebServer class thread as well as the main thread.  Is there anything that I am missing?

I know that I can create the two programs that can run in tandem as separate processes, but I was hoping to avoid any IPC and shoot for a single process with the data processing in one thread and a generic serversocket receiving data in a separate thread.  While I'm still new to all this, I'm fairly certain that this is one of those simple things that I have overlooked, but I would greatly appreciate any assistance you could provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `.run()` on a `Runnable` doesn't make it run in a new thread, it runs it in the current thread.

Did you mean to do `new Thread (server).start ()`?

Comment: Ah, I was completely forgetting that.  I used to simply extend the Thread class instead of utilizing the runnable interface.  That's years of not using Java for you.

Thanks!